# Using BATCH to get country and ISP name from an IP or Hostname?

Tags: batch-file, ip, ip-address, nslookup

I need to complete this job in Batch.

I use **NSLOOKUP** command to find the Hostname of an IP, But how I can locate the country of that IP And the ISP Name?

Is it possibly?

Thankyou for read.

**EDIT**: For example i want to do this in a bat code:

```
IP address  **.***.30.113
Hostname    **-***-30-113.rdns.blackberry.net
ISP Research In Motion UK Limited
Country United Kingdom United Kingdom
```

**EDIT 2**: I accept an external APP to do it, please

I've tryed "**whois**" from **sysinternals**, But it's giving me bad info cause if i put my local ip in the program, it gives me the city of the organization (**Madrid, Spain**), not the most nearest location of mi isp provider (**Valencia, Spain**), If i geo-locate my ip in internet it gives me the good info (**Valencia, Spain**)

Any ideas about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get that information without an IP-to-Country table.

Try http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecountry, it is free and works great.

Comment: Hi, Thankyou for the info, I have only a simple question, By "you cannot get that info" you mean only the country, or both info (country and ISP name?

Comment: Actually both. If you want ISP info as well, you can use http://www.maxmind.com/app/isp. Also, you can query RIPE database (https://www.ripe.net/data-tools/db), but ISP may not be as accurate.

Comment: thankyou again. And any external commandline app to get that info? I've tryed "whois" from sysinternals, But it's giving me bad info cause if i put my local ip in the program, it gives me the city of the organization (Madrid, Spain), not the most nearest location of mi isp provider (Valencia, Spain), if i geo-locate my ip in internet it gives me the good info (Valencia, Spain)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a batch file I coded that does an IP Lookup using ipinfo.io's API. https://pastebin.com/Ucs2Kuqn

```
echo sUrl = "http://ipinfo.io/%ip%/json" > %temp%\%webclient%.vbs
```